# Design pattern to process different file types in OOP

Tags: file, oop, design-patterns, pattern-matching

I need to process a big set of files that at the moment are all loaded into memory on a List.

i.e:

> List(FileClass) Files;

Use:

> Reader.Files; //List of files of the type

File Class has one attribute to match each FileInfo object property i.e: Name,CreateDate,etc.
Also has a List of Lines of the type  (LineNumber, Data).

Now I need to create an logic to interpret these files. They all have different logic interpreteations and they will be loaded on to their correspondent Business Object.

i.e:

```
Model model = new Model()

.emp => Process => Employee Class
.ord => Process => Order Class

model.AddObject(emp);
model.AddObject(ord);
```

My question what is the best design pattern for a problem of this sort.

All I can think of is... something like this:

```
public ProcessFiles(List<Files> Files)
{

Model model = new Model()
var obj;

        foreach(file in Files)
        {
                    switch (File.GetExtension(file))
                    {
                        case "emp":
                           obj = BuildEmployee(file) //returns Employee class type
                            break;
                        case "ord":
                            obj = BuildOrder(file) //returns Order class type
                            break;
                    }

         model.AddObject(obj);

        }

}
```

Is there a better way to approach this?
This solution looks procedural to me, is there a better Object Oriented Approach to it?

Cheers

**UPDATE:**

I've come across a few options to solve this:

1)- Use of Partial classes for separation of concerns.
I have a data model that I don't want to mix File processing, Database use, etc (Single Responsibility)

DATA MODEL:

```
public partial class Employee 
{ 
   public int EmployeeID; 
   public string FirstName; 
   public string LastName; 
   public decimal Salary; 
}
```

INTERPRETER/FILE PARSER:

This partial class defines the logic to parse .emp files.

```
         // This portion of the partial class to separate Data Model 
          from File processing
         public partial class Employee 
         { 
            public void ProcessFile(string FileName)
            { 
               //Do processing
            } 

            ... 
         }
```

**Intepreter Object**

```
 public class Interpreter : IInterpreter
     {

     foreach(file in Files)
      {

       switch (fileExtension)
        {
          case .emp
             Employee obj= new Employee();
          case .ord
             Order obj = new Order(file);
        }


        obj.ProcessFile(File)
        Model.AddObject(emp)
      }

     }
```

2)- Perhaps using some sort of Factory Pattern... 
The input is the file with an extension type.
This drives the type of object to be created (i.e: Employee, Order, anything) and also the logic to parse this file. Any ideas?

Comment: You are asking for an algorithm to solve your problem - not a design pattern. Base on your scenario, Employee and Order class should inherit from Model class. You need to study Abstract Class and Inheritance.

Comment: Thansk for your reply. Model is a type of context that hold those objects together in the ways of a "snapshot". Employees or Orders in this example aren't a type of Model. I can't see why I should inherit Model.. In this example Model could be like "a company" at a point in time, with employees and orders". I think there should be a better way, a pattern to solve this. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Well, it seems that you want to vary the processing behaviour based on the file type. Behaviour and Type being keywords. Does any behavioural pattern suit your requirement?

Or is it that the object creation is driven by the input file type? Then creation and type become important keywords.

You might want to take a look at strategy and factory method patterns.

Here is something from the book [Refactoring to Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351):

> The overuse of patterns tends to result from being patterns happy. We
>   are patterns happy when we become so enamored of patterns that we
>   simply must use them in our code. A patterns-happy programmer may work
>   hard to use patterns on a system just to get the experience of
>   implementing them or maybe to gain a reputation for writing really
>   good, complex code.
>
> A programmer named Jason Tiscione, writing on SlashDot (see
>   http://developers.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=33602&cid=3636102),
>   perfectly caricatured patterns-happy code with the following version
>   of Hello World. ..... It is perhaps impossible to avoid being patterns
>   happy on the road to learning patterns. In fact, most of us learn by
>   making mistakes. I've been patterns happy on more than one occasion.
>
> The true joy of patterns comes from using them wisely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. I am giving it a thought to the Strategy Pattern, also to the possibility of using partial classes as on my latests update to the post. Very nice pattern, I'll use it for object comparison so I can implement different algorithms. I can't discard using Factory Pattern, since the extension of the file drives the type of object to be used and the logic to parse the file.

Comment: Glad to provide pointers. Updated the answer because I thought you might be tending towards being patterns happy. Joshua Kerievsky's comment from the book saved me many times from being patterns happy.

Comment: Yes, it makes a lot of sense. So far implementing partial classes is my best bet. I have a base object that I can implement common functionality to all my implementations which makes it very easy to separate concerns using Partial Classes. Still learning best practices. Thanks very much for your interest and reply.